# Changing DelayValidation on multiple SSIS packages

Tags: ssis

I have a project with about 150 packages in SSIS 2012. One of them is the entry point and the rest are called somewhere down the line from the main. Each of them creates its own table in the destination if one does not exist. I've found that I need to set DelayValidation to True for this to work, but loathe the job of doing it 150 times. Is there a way to have this property propagate or anything other than making a change to all the packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make this change by using the .NET library. Below is a PowerShell script that looks at all the packages in a given folder. If the `DelayValidation` property is false, then it will change it to True and save the package.

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SQLServer.ManagedDTS") | Out-Null
$folder = "C:\sandbox\StackOverflow\StackOverflow\obj\Development"

$app = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application

foreach($current in (Get-ChildItem $folder -Filter "*.dtsx").FullName)
{
    Write-Host $current

    $package = $app.LoadPackage($current, $null)
    if ($package.DelayValidation -eq $false)
    {
        $package.DelayValidation = $true
        $app.SaveToXml($package, $null)
    }
}
```

### Caveats

- Never run automated code without testing that you have version control.
- This only changes the Package's DelayValidation. Each Container and Task have their own DelayValidation property that may need to be updated

### 2017+ note

A user noted

> SaveToXml function needs 3 parameter in SQL Server 2017.

That would make this `SaveToXml` look like

```
$app.SaveToXml($current, $package, $null)
```

The [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.application.savetoxml?view=sqlserver-2017) indicates this has been so since 2016.

They further noted,

> As a Developer without installing SQL Server like me, need located your Microsoft.SQLServer.ManagedDTS.dll file explicitly

That would replace the first line's `LoadWithPartialName` to LoadFile with an explicit path like

```
 ([Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSIS\140\Binn\Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll") | Out-Null)
```

Note the exact path will vary based on your installed tooling. I tend to use the `dir /s /b` (directory, search subfolders, bare format) command to find things so

```
C:\>cd "\Program Files (x86)"
C:\Program Files (x86)>dir /s /b Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSIS\150\Binn\Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\SSIS\150\Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll
```

Here we can see I have two ManagedDTS.dll both for the 150 (2019?) release of SQL Server

Comment: Thank you @billinkc! You come through as usual!

Comment: @billinkc I want to use this method but I'm getting an error when I run the line:

```
$app = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application
```

It states it can not load the assembly "Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap". Can you provide any pointers?

Comment: @MichaelSPalatsi Which approach are you working with? LoadWithPartialName or LoadFile?

Comment: @billinkc I attempted to use both, and I don't receive an error for either. I believe I have access to "Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll" but it runs into issues trying to hunt down "Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap.dll". Now, I have both of those DLLs in my visual studio folder. Can I simply point powershell to those?

Comment: @billinkc In addition, I'm noticing that "Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap.dll" is in GAC_32 folder and "Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll" is in GAC_MSIL. Neither folder have both... and I can't change these folders as I don't have admin privileges. Any path around this?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the quicker way, which is finding `DelayValidation">0<` and replacing with `DelayValidation">-1<` in the code of each individual package. It is quicker than going item by item and alter the properties, but you still have to do it for each package.

Answer (score 0):

Setting DelayValidation">0 to DelayValidation">-1 works in SSIS 2008 and SSIS 2008 R2, but it doesn't exists with SSIS 2012. By default, components in SSIS 2012 doesn't have the item - DTS:DelayValidation. Once you've set the component's DelayValidation to True, the following is added - DTS:DelayValidation="True". I'm using Visual Studio Ultimate 2012.